# Escaping $ in HEREDOC string with PHP

Tags: php, string, heredoc

I have something like this

```
$var = <<<HEREDOC
..."request": ${"hello"}...
HEREDOC;
```

Of course PHP thinks `${"hello"}` is a variable and it fails to load.

How to escape the $?

Comment: $var = <<<HEREDOC
..."request": \${"hello"}...
HEREDOC;

Comment: The PHP manual would have taught you right away: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
$var = <<<HEREDOC
..."request": \${"hello"}...
HEREDOC;
```

Answer (score 6):

The same way you escape almost anything in a string

```
$var = <<<HEREDOC
..."request": \${"hello"}...
HEREDOC;
echo $var;
```

RESULT

```
..."request": ${"hello"}...
```